# Doxygen produces strange namespaces

Tags: c++, doxygen

I've been trying for the past 3 hours to nail down particularly.. interesting problem with doxygen.

Problem is, Doxygen produces some interesting **@number** namespaces (@114, @347, @91 etc) for every anonymous namespace. The number of these is at times significant number (so there are places, where i have about 20 @something namespaces and just two real ones).

My settings exclude anonymous namespaces already. I revised namespace settings one by one; actually enabling anonymous namespaces produces "compiler readable" names for these @ items. I disabled my input filters to exclude possibility of having those injected by me. Essentially nothing of that helped.

is there maybe some interaction with certain almost unnoticed flag that force-enables generation of these items? how do i "kill" it? the web site is so clouded with @ items that it's almost pointless to use it.

thanks bunches!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @123 markers are used internally by doxygen. They should not appear in the output. If you see them in the latest version (currently 1.8.2), then please file a bug report in the bug tracker.

Comment: thanks; i'm using 1.8.1.1, i'll look up revision history and report it unless it's been fixed mean time.